# iPhone - draw a transparent (cleared) rectangle with customized border

Tags: iphone, border, drawrect, rectangles, cgcontextref

I'm trying to draw a rectangle, which should have black color border of width 5.0, I am getting the rectangle as seen below,

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
```

[image]

I can make it clear / transparent (white) background instead the green one showing right now with `[UIColor  whiteColor].CGColor` but then it should have black border also.

How do I set the customized border to rectangle?

Comment: White is not transparent, `[UIColor clearColor]` is the transparent color…

Comment: @Arkku, Yes! I am just trying to make it customized, you made it! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the stroke color and width as desired, for example:

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0f);
CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect);
```

If you are also filling the rectangle, do this *after* filling so the fill doesn't cover up the stroke.

Comment: Yes, its working! I need to do this after filling as you mentioned. Thank you :)